# Adding Kit Items to Sales Order Only Adding Last Line

Tags: acumatica

version 19.104

I am trying to add the items that make up a kit to a new sales order that I am making in code.  I'm adding the kit items as "free" items to the sales order.  My problem is that if I have more than one line to add to the sales order, only the kit items for the last line in my loop are added to the sales order.  Here's some code:

```
public PXSelect<INKitSpecStkDet, Where<INKitSpecStkDet.kitInventoryID, 
        Equal<Required<INKitSpecStkDet.kitInventoryID>>,
        And<INKitSpecStkDet.revisionID, 
        Equal<Required<INKitSpecStkDet.revisionID>>>>> KitStockItems;
....


    public PXAction<MyOrder> MyAction;

    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "My Action")]
    protected void myAction()
    {
        SOOrderEntry orderEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();

        using (PXTransactionScope transScope = new PXTransactionScope())
        {
            orderEntry.Clear();

            SOOrder newOrder = new SOOrder();
            newOrder.OrderType = PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderTypeConstants.SalesOrder;
            newOrder = orderEntry.CurrentDocument.Insert(newOrder); 

            newOrder.CustomerID = CurrentDocument.Current.CustomerID;
            newOrder.OrderDesc = CurrentDocument.Current.OrderDesc;
            newOrder.OrderDate = this.Accessinfo.BusinessDate;
            newOrder.ProjectID = CurrentDocument.Current.ProjectID;
            newOrder.BranchID = CurrentDocument.Current.BranchID;
            newOrder.Hold = true;

            newOrder.Status = PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderStatus.Hold;

            newOrder = orderEntry.CurrentDocument.Update(newOrder);
            orderEntry.Actions.PressSave();

            foreach (OrderLine line in Transactions.Select())  //TODO: If only one line in Transactions, no problems.
            {

                    SOLine newLine = orderEntry.Transactions.Insert();

                    newLine.LineType = PX.Objects.SO.SOLineType.Inventory;
                    newLine.Operation = PX.Objects.SO.SOOperation.Issue;
                    newLine.OrderType = newOrder.OrderType;

                    newLine.InventoryID = line.InventoryID;// 706;
                    newLine.BranchID = newOrder.BranchID;
                    newLine.Qty = line.OrderQty; // 1.0m;
                    newLine.CuryUnitPrice = line.CuryUnitPrice;// 20.0m;
                    newLine.CuryExtPrice = line.CuryUnitPrice;
                    newLine.UOM = line.Uom;// "EA";
                    newLine.SiteID = line.Siteid;// 159;

                    newLine = orderEntry.Transactions.Update(newLine);

                    orderEntry.Actions.PressSave();

                    //TODO: If more than one OrderLine, only last line kit items are added to sales order.
                    PXResultset<INKitSpecStkDet> resultSet = KitStockItems.Select(new object[] { line.InventoryID, line.KitRevisionID });
                    foreach (PXResult stkItem in resultSet)  
                    {
                        INKitSpecStkDet kitItem = stkItem.GetItem<INKitSpecStkDet>();
                        SOLine stkKitLine = orderEntry.Transactions.Insert();

                        stkKitLine.InventoryID = kitItem.CompInventoryID;
                        stkKitLine.Qty = kitItem.DfltCompQty * line.OrderQty;
                        stkKitLine.UOM = kitItem.UOM;
                        stkKitLine.IsFree = true;

                        stkKitLine = orderEntry.Transactions.Update(stkKitLine);
                        orderEntry.Actions.PressSave();
                    }


            }


            transScope.Complete();

        }

        this.Actions.PressSave();
```

Hopefully, this makes sense.  Any help would be great.

TIA!

Comment: First i would avoid the over persisting (do only one PressSave at the end). But I would look at the LineNbr of the SOLines being inserted as well as make sure SOOrder view current has a value as the current SOOrder is what drives the line counter for SOLine inserts. For example look at stkKitLine.LineNbr between each line and make sure its different

Comment: Yeah, I added all of the PressSave()s in order to try to resolve the issue.  I checked the SOLine Inserts on a debugger.  The lower "foreach (PXResult stkItem in resultSet) " is being entered appropriately - on each main line of the sales order that contains a kit item.  And, the Line number that is assigned seems to be OK.  After making a sales order with two kit items, I end up with line numbers 1,7,9 which is odd.  1 and 7 are the items that are kits.  There should be some order lines between 1 and 7.  I saw 3 and 5 assigned but, they didn't make it to the DB.  weird....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was missing a field on my sales order lines.  I set the Manual Discount to true and all is well.

```
 ....

 stkKitLine.IsFree = true;
 stkKitLine.ManualDisc = true; //added this

 ....
```